# Capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size= 5000]. Error occurs whenever I write something, or copy and paste from another project

Tags: errors

Ive just started a new project and whenever i define the packages, other than the default settings, overleaf cannot compile. it is like my working capacity is full, but there are just two other projects. Actually I wanted to copy and paste one of my projects into a new one, but then the error occurs. It is also there when I only define the Title page!
I am using a free account- is this the reason? What can I do about it?

[image: This is the Error message...]

Comment: The problems are not caused by limited storage capacity or account restrictions on Overleaf. This is a (common) LaTeX error that means that something is wrong in your code that leads to endless recursion or some kind of loop. To find out what the problem is with your code you should try to create the smallest possible file that leads to this error. Remove everything that you think is not related, Then paste it here in your question (using the `edit` button below the post).

Comment: As far as I know, the file `nil.ldf` is loaded with `\usepackage{babel}` and no language is passed as a global option. However, I can't reproduce the issue.